# Form without model, add to namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I recently added namespaces to my rails app. I had a form that will email owners, but it seems to have broken in the process (error at bottom). The form does not have a model, it just kicks off an email.

Here is my routes file

```
scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :email_owners do
      collection do
       get :email
       get :islas
       post :email
       post :islas
       end
      end
    end
  match "*path", to: "sites#not_found" # handles /en/fake/path/whatever
  end
root to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}") # handles /
match '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
end
```

Output of rake routes CONTROLLER=admin/email_owners

```
email_admin_email_owners GET    /:locale/admin/email_owners/email(.:format)    {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"email", :controller=>"admin/email_owners"}
islas_admin_email_owners GET    /:locale/admin/email_owners/islas(.:format)    {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"islas", :controller=>"admin/email_owners"}
                     POST   /:locale/admin/email_owners/email(.:format)    {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"email", :controller=>"admin/email_owners"}
                     POST   /:locale/admin/email_owners/islas(.:format)    {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"islas", :controller=>"admin/email_owners"}
  admin_email_owners GET    /:locale/admin/email_owners(.:format)          {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/email_owners"}
                     POST   /:locale/admin/email_owners(.:format)          {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/email_owners"}
new_admin_email_owner GET    /:locale/admin/email_owners/new(.:format)      {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/email_owners"}
edit_admin_email_owner GET    /:locale/admin/email_owners/:id/edit(.:format) {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/email_owners"}
   admin_email_owner GET    /:locale/admin/email_owners/:id(.:format)      {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/email_owners"}
                     PUT    /:locale/admin/email_owners/:id(.:format)      {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/email_owners"}
                     DELETE /:locale/admin/email_owners/:id(.:format)      {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/email_owners"}
```

app/controllers/admin/email_owners.rb

```
class Admin::EmailOwnersController < Admin::BaseController
  def email
  owner_type = params[:owner_type]
  subject = params[:subject]
  message = params[:message]

    owners = User.owners
    owners.each do |owner|
      OwnerMailer.all_owners(owner, subject, message).deliver
    end 
      flash[:notice] = "Email has been sent to all Owners"
      redirect_to admin_sites_path
  end 
end
```

and here is my form, where the problem is.

```
<%= form_tag [:admin, email_admin_email_owners_path] do %>
To:
  <%= radio_button_tag "owner_type", "All" %> All Owners |
  <%= radio_button_tag "owner_type", "FullTime" %> FullTime |
  <%= radio_button_tag "owner_type", "PartTime" %> PartTime<br />
  <%= text_field_tag "subject", "Subject" %><br />
  <%= text_area_tag "message", "Message" %><br />
  <%= submit_tag "Send Email" %>
<% end %>
```

Whenever I go to the route/path
(http://localhost:3000/en/admin/email_owners/email)

I get the error

```
undefined method `admin_/en/admin/email_owners/email_path' for #<#<Class:0x789db30>:0x789ab78>
```

But i'm not sure why. Any ideas? Am I calling the wrong path? Thanks

Comment: Try <%= form_tag email_admin_email_owners_path do %>

Comment: That worked, thanks so much. Post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form_tag takes an url as the first argument, so you should only specify the route you want it to go to:

```
<%= form_tag email_admin_email_owners_path do %>
```

Rails uses square-brackets as shortcuts to generate nested paths from strings, symbols or objects, so `[:admin, :email]` would generate the `admin_email_path`

When you used square-brackets like `[:admin, email_admin_email_owners_path]` to generate this url two things happened:

1. email_admin_email_owners_path returns '/en/admin/email_owners/email'
2. evaluated within the square-brackets with :admin then gives you  `admin_/en/admin/email_owners/email_path` which is an undifined method

Comment: Thanks for going above and beyond and explaining this for me. I appreciate it!